# bash: /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I recently uninstalled oneAPI and this error appears every time I open the termianl.
The same thing happens when i run `$ bash` on terminal

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?? What error? Please edit the question and add details not in comments. Why did you uninstall this Oneapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably in your `~/.bashrc` file.

`grep oneapi ~/.bashrc` may show that line.

Edit it in your favourite text editor, and remove the call to the missing script.

`gedit ~/.bashrc` or `nano ~/.bashrc`, whatever you prefer. Remove the line carefully and save.

Comment: I love you man.