# Unexpected output appears whenever I open a terminal

Tags: software-installation

[image: oneAPI environment initialized... and many more lines]

I always see this when I open my terminal. What is the way out please?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead, please copy the text, paste the text into your question, and format it properly. Help us to help you.

Comment: Most likely this is due to something that has been added to your `~/.bashrc`. Compare that file with `/etc/skel/.bashrc` (the system default version) for clues.

Comment: Looks like there is something like oneAPI installed which causes the issue. oneAPI is not part of the standard Ubuntu installation. So it's quite likely that you installed oneAPI not correctly.

Comment: Related: [bash: /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466588/bash-opt-intel-oneapi-setvars-sh-no-such-file-or-directory). See also [Set Environment Variables for CLI Development](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dlft-toolkit/get-started-guide-linux/2021-1/before-you-begin.html#DLFSETVARS). My *guess* is you added something like `. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh` to your `~/.bashrc` more than one time.